# Textbook on Lebesgue integral via functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

It is well known that the completion of $C[0,1]$ with the norm given by $\|f\|=\int_0^1|f|$ is $L^1(0,1)$ and that the extension of the Riemann integral functional to $L^1(0,1)$ is the Lebesgue integral. I want to teach the Lebesgue integral in $(0,1)$ without using measure theory neither the Daniell Integral. I want some practical (calculus) tools to compute Lebesgue integrals and to decide when a function is in $L^1(0,1)$ or not.  I want to use only the concept of zero measure sets.

Denote with $$\mathcal L^1(0,1)=\{f \,:\,\exists f_n \in C[0,1] \text{ Cauchy  and } f_n(x)\to f(x) \text{ a.e. }(0,1) \}/\text\{f\,:\, f(x)=0 \text{ a.e. }(0,1)\}.$$ I have done some computations and I think it is possible to prove that $\mathcal L^1(0,1)$ is the same thing that $L^1(0,1)$ with its natural identification, but I am not happy with those computations. Some of them are a little bit messy.

¿Is there some text that develop those ideas? I don't care if it is heavy reading or it has an abstract configuration.

Comment: I don't know of any texts that cover this but what would be the point of doing this? Also, how do you expect to introduce measure zero sets without measure theory?

Comment: When you say $f_n(x)\to f(x) \text{ a.e. }$ on $(0,1)$, you're using measure theory.

Comment: No. Im not using measure theory. Just the concept of zero measure set. It can be defined without measure theory (again) see for example Mathematical Analysis Apostol definition 7.43 and theorem 7.48. Spivak (Calculus on Manifolds) use the same concept and the book does not touch any other measure theory stuf.

Comment: In fact Daniell Integral use the same concept of zero measure set and with this constructs measure theory. See for example the construction of measure of Mathematical Analysis of Tom Apostol in the Lebesgue integral chapters.